# PHP & MySQL - get top level category with just one query

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to get the first category (level zero, no parents) from a child category (which might be any level) with just one query with `MySQL`. Is that possible?

Here's an example `DB` structure :

```
Table categories

    id (INT 11)
    parent (INT 11, zero if it has no parent)
    name
```

**edit**: Would `MPTT` be a easier solution to the problem?

Comment: How is `top` category define?  NULL parent?

Comment: @AleksG it's defined as `0` (integer).

Comment: I suspect you can't do this with one simple query.  You should be able to write a stored function to do this - and then use one select from the code to call that function.

Comment: So I guess `MPTT` is the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to scan infinite levels with only one query but if you are sure your categoies tree doesn't go deeper than a certain number of levels you can use this trick, this is for 4 levels:

```
SELECT COALESCE(c4.parent, c3.parent, c2.parent, c1.parent)
 FROM categories AS c1
 LEFT JOIN categories AS c2 ON( c1.parent = c2.id )
 LEFT JOIN categories AS c3 ON( c2.parent = c3.id )
 LEFT JOIN categories AS c4 ON( c3.parent = c4.id )
 WHERE c1.id = {someID}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with a [stored function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines.html) and [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). You may run into an endless loop, so take care.